# Segmentation fault w/ vectors

Tags: c++, vector

The program i'm doing is not completing the for loop and it throws me Segmentation fault error before it the loop is finished. May i ask if its because the loop is too small?

```
for(vector<string>::iterator it = passList.begin(); it!= passList.end();it++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < passList.size()-1; ++x)
        {
            while(passList[x] == used)
            {
                x++;
            }
                firstPW = passList[x];
                cout << firstPW << endl;
                //passList.erase(remove(passList.begin(), passList.end(), firstPW), passList.end());
                replace (passList.begin(), passList.end(), firstPW, used);
                chainHead.push_back(firstPW);
                strmd5 = MD5Hash(firstPW);
                //chainTail.push_back(strmd5);
                //cout << strmd5 << endl;

                strmd5.erase(remove_if(strmd5.begin(), strmd5.end(), isnonnum), strmd5.end());
                cout << strmd5 << endl;

                numOfDigits = strmd5.length();
                //cout << numOfDigits << endl;

                digitsToMinus = numOfDigits - to_string(count).length();
                strmd5.erase(strmd5.length()-digitsToMinus);
                cout << strmd5 << endl;

                intmd5 = stoi(strmd5);
                //cout << intmd5 << endl;
                intmd5 = intmd5 + 1;
                index = intmd5 % count;
                cout << index << endl;

                chainHead2.push_back(chainHead[0]);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            firstPW = passList2[index];
            //cout << firstPW << endl;
            //passList.erase(remove(passList.begin(), passList.end(), firstPW), passList.end());
            replace (passList.begin(), passList.end(), firstPW, used);
            //chainHead.push_back(firstPW);
            strmd5 = MD5Hash(firstPW);
            chainTail.push_back(strmd5);
            //cout << strmd5 << endl;

            strmd5.erase(remove_if(strmd5.begin(), strmd5.end(), isnonnum), strmd5.end());
            //cout << strmd5 << endl;

            numOfDigits = strmd5.length();
            //cout << numOfDigits << endl;

            digitsToMinus = numOfDigits - to_string(count).length();
            strmd5.erase(strmd5.length()-digitsToMinus);
            //cout << strmd5 << endl;

            intmd5 = stoi(strmd5);
            //cout << intmd5 << endl;
            //intmd5 = intmd5 + 1;
            index = intmd5 % count;
            //cout << index << endl;
            if(i = 3)
            {
                temp = chainTail.back();
                chainTail2.push_back(temp);
            } 
        }
        chainHead.clear();
        chainTail.clear();
        /*for(int a=0; a<chainHead2.size(); a++)
        {
            cout << chainHead2[a] << endl;
        }
        for(int b=0; b<chainTail2.size(); b++)
        {
            cout << chainTail2[b] << endl;
        }*/
        PWchain = chainHead2[0];
        HASHchain = chainTail2[0];
        chainHead2.clear();
        chainTail2.clear();

        Rainbowtxt.open("Rainbow.txt",ios::app);

        Rainbowtxt << PWchain << " " << HASHchain << endl;
        Rainbowtxt.close();
    }
```

I have tried changing the variable names so that they wouldn't collide but the errors is still the same. I appreciate any advice to improve my code too.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a [mcve].

Comment: have you tried debugging? you have no check that `x` is a valid value inside your while loop

Comment: @Ron, Which part should i edit out? I just paste a part of my code which i think is responsible for the error.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I assume the x value is taken from the for loop just right above it. Which is the index of the vector passList.

Comment: @jonathanhojh "_I just paste a part of my code which i think is responsible for the error._" That's a problem for multiple reasons: 1) You _think_ that the problem is here, while there is non-zero chance that the problem is in an unrelated piece of code. 2) You should provide us with **manufactured** [mcve]. The piece of code, that is as minimal as possible, but sufficient enough for us to copy-paste it, and reproduce the same problem.

Comment: `x` is taken from the for loop but you then increment it and don't check it remains less than `passList.size()`

Comment: @Ron, Even if i paste the whole of my code it wouldn't run as i'm using a library. i would gladly take down this post if i'm violating any rules here.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I did not thought of that! Thank you so much!

Comment: @jonathanhojh "_Even if i paste the whole of my code it wouldn't run as i'm using a library._" That's the thing: no-one asked for you to copy-paste the entire code. All we did was: asked to provide [mcve]. Those aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < passList.size()-1; ++x)
{
    while(passList[x] == used)
    {
        x++;
    }
```

You have no bounds check on the value of `x` after you increment it inside the while loop, this is likely to lead to accessing items outside the bounds of `passList`.